# geom_freqpoly starting from below zero

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a histogram plot and superimpose a frequency polygon on it using ggplot. When I add the frequency polygon the first observation it shows is -ve, as shown in the image. Is there a way to define the `geom_freqpoly` function so that the polygon starts from the first bin?

```
dat<-as.data.frame(rexp(1000,0.2))
g <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = dat[,1])) 
g + geom_histogram(alpha = 0.2, binwidth = 5, colour = "black") + geom_freqpoly(binwidth = 5, size = 1)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjeDm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the histogram data from the plot, then use `geom_line` to plot a line over the bars:

```
dat <- as.data.frame(rexp(1000,0.2))

g <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = dat[,1])) +
  geom_histogram(alpha = 0.2, binwidth = 5, colour = "black")
gb <- ggplot_build(g)
g  + geom_line(data = gb$data[[1]], aes(x=x, y=y), size = 1)
```

Which gives you [image: this output].